# При использовании вебпака 5-го не подключается шрифт к html. В чем моя ошибка?

Tags: html, css, webpack

Пишу проект с использованием вебпака. Но при указанной ниже конфигурации вебпака шрифт не подключается
/webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
console.log(__dirname);
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";
const optimization = () => {
    const config = {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all"
        }
    };

    if (!isDev) {
        config.minimizer = [new CssMinimizerPlugin(), new TerserWebpackPlugin()];
    }

    return config;
};

const cssLoaders = (extra) => {
    const loaders = [
        {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
                publicPath: ""
            }
        }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
        },
    ]

    if (extra) {
        loaders.push(extra)
    }

    return loaders;
}

console.log('IsDev:', isDev);

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname),
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
    output:
        {
            filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
        },

    optimization: optimization(),

    devServer: {
        port: 4200
    },

    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin(
            {
                title: 'Funiro',
                template: "./index.html",
                minify: {
                    collapseWhitespace: !isDev
                }
            }
        ),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(
            {filename: "[name].[contenthash].css"}
        )
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: cssLoaders()
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'src/img/[name].[ext]',
                    publicPath: ''
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'src/fonts/'
                        }
                    }
                ],
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

/src/css/fonts.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Regular';
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('../fonts/Gilroy-Regular.woff') format('font-woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold';
    src: url('./../fonts/Gilroy-Bold.woff') format('font-woff');
    font-weight: 700;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Semibold';
    font-weight: 600;
    src: url('../fonts/Gilroy-Semibold.woff') format('font-woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Medium';
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url('../fonts/Gilroy-Medium.woff') format('font-woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Icons';
    src: url('../fonts/icons.woff') format('font-woff');
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

/src/css/styles.css

```
@import './fonts.css';
@import './icons.css';

.main-class {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 48px;
}
```

Шрифты подключаю в index.js

```
import './fonts/Gilroy-Bold.woff';
import './fonts/Gilroy-Medium.woff';
import './fonts/Gilroy-Regular.woff';
import './fonts/Gilroy-Semibold.woff';
import './fonts/icons.woff';
import './css/styles.css';
```

В DevTools стиль якобы применен, но визуально видно, что шрифт не применился который необходим. Во вкладке "Network", подключаемый файл шрифта отсутствует.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем заключается моя ошибка?

Comment: Советую в первую очередь проверить наличие файлов шрифтов в сборке, соотнести их с URL в собранных css-файлах (может файлы шрифтов собрались, но "не туда"), а также попробовать использовать алиас пути вместо `../` (с вебпаком, в [S]CSS вроде символ `~` используется как алиас `src`, но этот момент могу помнить неверно, и его лучше уточнить по дебаг-выводу конфига / в документации).

Comment: @yar85 при сборке проекта в корне директории есть файлы шрифта проименованные по шаблону [contenthash].woff в них содержится это: export default __webpack_public_path__ + "src/fonts/Gilroy-Regular.woff"; замена ../ на ~/ не помогла. А где этот момент можно уточнить? не понимаю где искать

Comment: _«в них содержится это: export default ...»_ - а ты точно сборку смотришь, то есть файлы в `dist` после выполнения `npm run build`? И попробуй изменить в конфиге `outputPath: 'src/fonts/'` на `outputPath: 'fonts/'`. Хотя я не могу понять, как у тебя все-таки собралось, какая структура папок в `dist` и какие пути в собранных css-файлах получились... Ну а про алиас `~` - это я перепутал, сорри: [из `sass-loader`'а](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#resolving-import-at-rules) вспомнил, он тут не используется (то есть, информация про алиас лишняя).

Comment: @yar85 если описать словами то в dist/ хранятся файлы с паттерном(если я правильно называю) [contenthash].woff с указанным выше содержимым. Имеется также папка dist/src/fonts/ в которой хранятся все подключенные файлы шрифтов с нормальным указанием их названий. Прошу прощения, забыл добавить, что такая проблема наблюдается не только при сборке проекта, но и при запуске dev-server'a вебпака

Comment: ссылка на скриншот проекта с директорией сборки: http://prntscr.com/1cy29dr

Comment: @yar85 хотел бы также уточнить у Вас. Я начинаю изучать веб-разработку. Возможно до конца не понимаю необходимость использование вебпака. Его целесообразно использовать только при сборке проекта? При верстке макета его использование нежелательно ввиду замедления разработки в случае возникновения подобных ошибок? Благодарю Вас за терпение

Comment: Скриншот частично прояснил, но это только треть дела - еще надо убедиться в правильной "сборке" файлов шрифтов (в их содержимом не должно быть кода), и соотнести фактические пути с путями в собранных css-файлах. У меня сейчас нет такого кол-ва времени чтобы воссоздавать структуру проекта и проблему с его сборкой, увы. А _«необходимость использование вебпака»_ - зависит от проекта. Для всяких маленьких, типа лэндингов, можно взять сборщик попроще (parcel/vite/...). И в ошибках от нежелания разбираться, инструмент не виноват. Вебпак это прекрасный надежный сборщик, хоть и относительно медленный.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127672/discussion-between-yar85-and--).